# How can I achieve installing a application like Jenkins into a running CentOs container running inside a CentOs image using chef-recipe?

Tags: docker, chef-infra, docker-compose, dockerfile, chef-recipe

How can I achieve installing a application like Jenkins into a running CentOs container running inside a CentOs image using chef-recipe?

```
docker_service 'default' do
  action [:create, :start]
end
# Pull latest image
docker_image node['chef-docker']['docker-platform'] do
  tag 'latest'
  action :pull
end
# Run container 
docker_container node['chef-docker']['container-name'] do
  repo node['chef-docker']['container-repo']
  command '/bin/bash'
  port '80:80'
  tty true
  action :run
  end
docker_exec 'touch_it' do
  container 'First'
  command [***????????***]
end
```

Comment: Please stop asking the same question over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this is a very unusual use case and not the way docker is intended to be used. Usually, you would build a docker image which includes jenkins or use an existing jenkins docker image.

This is the official jenkins docker image: https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/

Is there a reason why you need to do it this way around?

Comment: My requirement changes on users requests. So pulling jenkins docker image is not recommended in my product.

Comment: I don't see a docker_exec resource available in chef-docker. You shouldn't need the docker_container resource which runs bash. You should just be able to issue the commands you want directly using docker_container: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/docker#docker_container Have a look here for commands to install jenkins on centos: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Red+Hat+distributions

Comment: @Bhave To supp CamW, learn how docker works before trying to automate it with Chef. If you have no clue what a resource is doing you'll never use it properly. Docker is not mean to run a shell but a process, it should run jenkins directly. If jenkins is not installed, bake an image first, then you may use chef inside the container to configure and start jenkins, but really start getting things done out of chef first to get a proper insight of what is doing what.